# iterating through different pandas dataframe names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 17 dataframes with similar names (df1, df2, df3,...) and would like to be able to write a for loop that will perform the same operations on each of the dataframes.

```
    df1 = pd.read_csv("filename1")
    df2 = pd.read_csv("filename2")
    ...
    df17 = pd.read_csv("filename17")

    for i in range (1,17):
        "operations"
```

How can I iterate through the names of these dataframes in the for loop?

Comment: Put the dataframes in a list or dictionary, then you can use your loop as so: `for df in dfs: ....`  I'd also recommend putting your filenames in a list or other data structure, so you can loop through them as well when reading in your dataframes.

Comment: You can do `locals()['df{}'.format(i)]`.

Comment: @user3483203 Could you put this as a complete answer ?  That would help unfortunate people, for example one like me-- searching for the last 12 hours, to find an answer on how to change the format of a particular column to `datetime` with ```df['BillDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BillDate']``` where `df` would be ultimately replaced by a sequence of dataframe names, e.g. in `dflist = [df1, df2, ..., df17]`

Answer (score 1):

Just you can put them into list as user3483203 mentioned at comment , then we using `pd.concat` with `keys` , afther that we using `groupby` to implement your function

```
l=[df1,df2...]
alldf=pd.concat(l,keys=list(range(len(l))))
allldf=alldf.groupby(level=0).apply('your function')
```

After the result we can using `groupby` split the data frame again

```
[x for _,x in alldf.groupby(level=0)]
```